# MYSQL/PHP Where can i insert

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible somehow to color "company_owner" by the code which user_color holds? That when you open select list, for the sample: Richerson, Rick would be colored by the code which **user** table has **user_color**.

```
$q->addQuery('user_id');
$q->addQuery('user_color');
$q->addQuery('CONCAT_WS(", ",contact_last_name,contact_first_name)');   

<tr>
   <tr>
       <td align="right">
           <?php echo $AppUI->_('Kompanijos savininkas'); ?>:
       </td>
       <td>
           <?php
               echo arraySelect($owners, 'company_owner', 'size="1" class="text"', 
                 ((@$obj->company_owner) ? $obj->company_owner : $AppUI->user_id));
           ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Yes, with inline css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch the content in user_table, register it into a var and parse it in html or in css, don't know how do that in mysqli but if you want I can write it in mysql

Comment: Can we have a chat in skype program or smth?

Comment: Sure, my skype is bingobongo9898